# Deserialize Razor encoded form data (in JSON) for

Tags: c#, .net, json, razor

I would like to deserialize the following json string representing form data to an object. The original object contained List elements(that was rendered using Razor)

```
{  
   "Office":"10649273-8412-4ac0-9109-085b04b49964",
   "SearchItemList[0].Column":"Account",
   "SearchItemList[0].Operation":"0",
   "SearchItemList[0].Value":"be5a36a7-c301-44d7-8d40-85e9637b5b14",
   "SearchItemList[1].Column":"",
   "SearchItemList[1].Operation":"0",
   "SearchItemList[1].Value":"",
   "SearchItemList[2].Column":"",
   "SearchItemList[2].Operation":"0",
   "SearchItemList[2].Value":"",
   "SearchItemList[3].Column":"",
   "SearchItemList[3].Operation":"0",
   "SearchItemList[3].Value":"",
   "SearchItemList[4].Column":"",
   "SearchItemList[4].Operation":"0",
   "SearchItemList[4].Value":"",
   "SearchItemList[5].Column":"",
   "SearchItemList[5].Operation":"0",
   "SearchItemList[5].Value":""
}
```

Comment: how did you end up with this JSON in the first place? what is your overall goal here besides deserializing this JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Your question didn't specify what kind of object you wanted to deserialize into.  If you don't really care, the quick-and-dirty way would be to deserialize this JSON into a `Dictionary<string, string>`.  Then you can pick out whatever keys you want from that-- they will be the same as what is in the JSON.  For example (I'm using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) here):

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
Console.WriteLine(dict["SearchItemList[0].Column"] + ": " + dict["SearchItemList[0].Value"]);
```

This would output:

```
Account: be5a36a7-c301-44d7-8d40-85e9637b5b14
```

However, I suspect what you are really looking for is to get the data back into some kind of class structure resembling the "original object", which I would assume looks something like this:

```
class RootObject
{
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public List<SearchItem> SearchItemList { get; set; }
}

class SearchItem
{
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public string Operation { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

To do that, you can deserialize the JSON into a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), then transform it from there into the desired result using standard `System.Linq` methods:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
RootObject root = new RootObject
{
    Office = (string)obj["Office"],
    SearchItemList = 
        obj.Properties()
           .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("SearchItemList["))
           .Select(p =>
           {
               var parts = p.Name.Split(new string[] { "[", "]." }, 3, StringSplitOptions.None);
               return new
               {
                   Index = int.Parse(parts[1]),
                   Property = new JProperty(parts[2], p.Value)
               };
           })
           .GroupBy(a => a.Index)
           .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
           .Select(g => new JObject(g.Select(a => a.Property)).ToObject<SearchItem>())
           .ToList()
};
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nQ2D2F